# Exporting a UIImage as a stretchableImage exports the image with horizontal and vertical lines drawn over the Image

Tags: ios, uiimage

I trying to build an app which combines a background image with text bubbles on top of it. I have text bubbles initialized as stretchable UIImages with leftCapWidth and topCapHeight defined. While displaying the text bubbles in the app itself everything works fine and the text bubbles are displayed normally without any lines drawn on top of them.

However when I try to export the images, I combine the background image with text bubbles on top using the  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() function I see that the text bubbles have a vertical line and a horizontal line drawn on them. They seem to be drawn at the point defined by the leftCapWidth and topCapHeight. Anyone faced such an issue before?

The only difference I see in rendering the image in my app and exporting it is that I use UIImageViews to hold the stretchable images while exporting I am just using UIImages.

Code for combining a bubble image to a background image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainImage.size);

[fullSectionImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, mainImage.size.width, mainImage.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0 ];

UIImage *bubbleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble1.png"];
stretchableImage = [bubbleImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:15];
[stretchableImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(originX,originY,width,height) blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0 ];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil,nil,nil);
```

Code for displaying the same bubble with the background image in the app:

```
UIImageView *bubbleImageView;
UIImage *bubbleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bubble1.png"];
stretchableImage = [bubbleImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:40 topCapHeight:15];
bubbleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:stretchableImage];
[bubbleImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
bubbleImageView.autoresizingMask = YES;
[self addSubview:bubbleImageView];
```

Comment: a screenshot (of the bad exported image) would be helpful, too, if you can add it.

Comment: [Screenshots](http://mayankmahajan.imgur.com/all/) .Stack Overflow did not allow me to add pictures. I have uploaded them at the link specified.

Comment: Anyone? Still can't seem to figure out.

Comment: can you show the code where you create your stretchable image, so we can see exactly what the caps are that you're defining?  the more information, the easier it is to help.  the code using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` wouldn't hurt to see, either.

Comment: added the code blocks. Hope that helps.

Comment: it helps, but it's still not enough.  you have lots of variables in your code that aren't defined in what we can see (`fullSectionImage, mainImage, originX, originY, width, height`).  in order for us to help you, it's important to give us enough to reproduce the problem.  I tried with the code snippets you gave, and ran on a 5.0 simulator, and I didn't see the problem (it worked fine).  but, I had to guess at some of the values you used.

Comment: also, just looking at the code, there's a couple things that don't look quite right.  first, `autoresizingMask` is not a `BOOL`, so it shouldn't be set to `YES`. also, in your first code snippet, you call `[stretchableImage drawInRect` **first**, and then assign `stretchableImage = ` right **after** that.  why is that?

Comment: The variables are actually being used in the code and do not have any specific values apart from the fact that they are float values. This gave me a hint to check the values of those variables and it turns out that when I draw the stretchableImage in a rectangle with 'originX, originY, width, height' as float values those lines appear. I convert them to integer values and the problem is solved. 
Thanks Nate for some good pointers. The assignment of 'stretchableImage =' after the drawInRect method was my fault in copying the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve this issue the stretchableImage should use drawInRect method with all integer values as arguements.

```
[stretchableImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(originX,originY,width,height) blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0 ];
```

originX, originY, width, height need to be integer values in this case. This solved the issue for me.